# iOS - Is is possible to pause execution, allow the main loop to run, then resume execution?

Tags: ios, cocoa

Is is possible in an iOS app to do the following:

- Pause execution of a method running on the main thread.
- Allow the main thread to continue, completing one loop of the main run loop (or continuing for a specified time period)
- Resume execution of the previous paused method
  ?

I've searched and can't find anything that allows me to do this, but I have a feeling I've seen it done in the past by a programmer I previously worked with.

The motivation for this is the following:

- I'm writing a test of a message routing class
- The test (a) sends a message and then (b) analyses the outcome to determine if the test passed
- The send message is sent using performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:NO

There are 2 ways I can think to resolve this:

1. Split my test up and use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:
2. Specify YES for waitUntilDone when sending the message

Both of these solutions are ok, but 1. complicates the test quite a lot, and 2. changes the messaging system I'm writing tests for, so will have to be carefully considered.

Considering what performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:YES does, it seems like the functionality I'm asking for should be possible (as it's similar in many ways), but is it possible?

Comment: You can use GCD to accomplish this. But can you try to edit your question to make it more clear ?

Comment: Yup sure, what part isn't clear?

Comment: You are facing a typical and probably common asynchronous problem. But you are not using the proper terminology. Thus, we don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. I bet the solution is quite easy ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper - that's probably why I couldn't find the answer when searching earlier! ;) Care to elaborate on where I was going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate date]];
```

This will execute one iteration of the main run loop and then continue on from there.  This is kind of abusing the way the run loop is supposed to work though, so you might want to consider a different design - it's almost never a good idea to pause the main thread.  Maybe do what you need to do in a separate thread and have that thread call back to a delegate method when it's done, or use a notification.

Comment: For normal things, this might seem like bad design, but for writing a test case for an async op, this is the exact correct approach. Once the test method - on the main thread - exits, the test is over; so if you need to queue and run a main queue completion routine before that happens, spinning the run loop yourself is the way to do it. I wrote myself a wrapper class around a CGD Dispatch Group with a "busy wait" method that does exactly this, it's very handy.

Comment: This achieves exactly what I want (thanks!), with execution of my method being paused for one run loop of the main thread, and then resuming from where I placed this call. @rgeorge - yup agreed it seems like the right design pattern to me to perform such a test

Answer (score 0):

Use multithreading for this purpose. SENDER on the mainThread, WATCHER on a secondThread, what allows you to start WATCHING before SENDING.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for an easy way to do this for my test code - ideally I'd like a 'magic' function that pauses execution of the method until another iteration of the main loop has completed. I'm thinking that this is probably not possible now, so will probably write something using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: instead :(